# How do I connect SQL*Plus with Java using netbeans?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have been trying to connect SQL*Plus with Java using Netbeans. I have researched many different questions and answers and I couldnt find anything that would work.

I can't seem to use the correct DB URL for `DriverManager.getConnection();`

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The database backend is an Oracle database or not? You should look for documentation on using that

Comment: You don't need netbeans for connect to something, place your code here.

Comment: Post your code and the exception message. Note that you aren't connecting to/from SQL*Plus; you are connecting to Oracle from Java.